# using python's requests-html to bypass adblock by executing js

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests, adblock

I was aiming to use requests HTML to be able to get text loaded by js. The static HTML displays a message requesting turning off AdBlock. I'm using the code below that is supposed to execute js but still, the HTML I get is static. Could anyone offer advice on how to resolve this, or at least explain why I'm not getting the dynamic content? And why do AdBlock messages still turn up?

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession 

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://wyborcza.pl/7,173236,25975806,free-khaled-drareni.html')
r.html.render()

print(r.html.html)
```

Comment: what text are you trying to get?

Comment: e.g. article text

Comment: you could try using Selenium to get the page to render, then parse it

Comment: yes, that won't be an issue with Selenium but I'm looking for more efficient solutions, therefore trying with requests-html